# How to make this kind of view using UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I need help. How can I design this kind of view

[image]

I'm using `UICollectionView` for this but all cell comes in a sequence i.e. 4 cell in each row. This Data is coming from `json`. So that array size is not fixed. Please help me how can I do this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: With a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` it's possible.

Comment: Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568074/floating-autolayout-ios-osx

Comment: I'm new in iOS. Can you please explain or give a sample how can I do this.

Comment: Is it fixed that odd row have 5 cell and even row have 4 cell. If Yes than I think you can try this via different sector in collection view i.e. odd sector have 5 cell and even sector have 4 cell and make cell horizontally center align.

Comment: @Dev.RK Yes, my first row have 4 cell and second row have 5 cell and others in same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a couple of hours, here is my own logic to make this kind of view which is small and easy to understand. Hope this will solve your problem and let me know if you have any confusion.

Try this-

Take two `global` `NSMutableArray` and an `int` variable i.e.

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray; // holds sequence of value i.e. 1,2,3.....,23
NSMutableArray *sectorArray; // holds sector array
int numOfSection; // holds numberOfSections
```

here is the **main logic** in `viewDidLoad()`-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    sectorArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    jsonArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23", nil];

    numOfSection= (int)ceilf(jsonArray.count/4.0); //devide jsonArray into section by deviding minimum cell in a row i.e. 4 for ex. 23/4 =5.75 and after ceilf() it is 6.

    int rangeVar=0; // check range for splitting jsonArray into sector.

    for (int i=0; i<numOfSection; i++) { // for loop will run 6 times i.e. 0-5

        if (rangeVar<jsonArray.count) { // check range must be less then jsonArray.count otherwise it crash the app

            if (i%2==0) { //for even/odd secionArray

                if (jsonArray.count>rangeVar+4) { // check jsonArroy count is gretter than rangeVar+4 otherwise add remaining values. Below i have evaluated jsonArray how this work.

                    [sectorArray addObject:[jsonArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeVar, 4)]];//j=0-- 1234 j=2-- 10111213 j=4 19202122

                }else{

                    [sectorArray addObject:[jsonArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeVar, jsonArray.count-rangeVar)]];

                }

                rangeVar+=4; // for next time range start from 4

            }else{

                if (jsonArray.count>rangeVar+5) {

                    [sectorArray addObject:[jsonArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeVar, 5)]];// j=1-- 56789 j=3 1415161718 j=5 23

                }else{

                    [sectorArray addObject:[jsonArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeVar, jsonArray.count-rangeVar)]];

                }

                rangeVar+=5;
            }

        }else{

            numOfSection-=1; // if you have 27 items than numOfSection is 7 but item 6 section are enough to hold all items.
        }

    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

//collectionView dataSource/Delegate methods

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *lblNumber=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
    lblNumber.layer.cornerRadius=lblNumber.frame.size.height/2;
    lblNumber.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
    lblNumber.layer.borderColor=[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    lblNumber.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    lblNumber.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sectorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    lblNumber.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblNumber];

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return numOfSection;
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [[sectorArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

// horizontally center align all cells

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger cellCount = [collectionView.dataSource collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
    if( cellCount >0 )
    {
        CGFloat cellWidth = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionViewLayout).itemSize.width+((UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionViewLayout).minimumInteritemSpacing;
        CGFloat totalCellWidth = cellWidth*cellCount;
        CGFloat contentWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width-collectionView.contentInset.left-collectionView.contentInset.right;
        if( totalCellWidth<contentWidth )
        {
            CGFloat padding = (contentWidth - totalCellWidth) / 2.0;
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, padding, 0, padding);
        }
    }
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

the main logic behind this is to split array into subarray and make different `section` as number of `subarrays` and add all `subarrays` into one `mutableArray`. Than work with this mainArray.

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dev.RK it solved my problem.. thank you for explaining the answer easy to understand for beginner.

Comment: Happy to help you dear:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create like this by using the custom collection view something like same as reference link in comment .

for handling the this design-

create a grid by using two diminutional arrey and calculate the row 
odd and even and create like same view.